# Independent subquery in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT TOP(1) COMPANYNAME FROM dbo.table1) AS COMPANYNAME FROM dbo.table2
```

How can we achieve the same query in LINQ, in a single attempt?
I tried the following code

```
var qry=from o in db.table2.tolist()
Select new {
o.ID,
COMPANYNAME=(db.table1.firstordefault())
};
```

But unfortunately an exception occurred i.e all threads need to be run etc...
Please help me out,
I googled but could not find a positive relevant result.

Comment: Try something like this table2.Select(t => new { t.ID, CompanyName = table1.Take(1).Select(t => t.CompanyName).Single() } ).ToList(). I assume that

Comment: If scenario like
SELECT ID, (SELECT TOP(1) COMPANYNAME FROM dbo.table1 where activedate between dbo.table2.date1 and dbo.table1.date2) AS COMPANYNAME FROM dbo.table2

Comment: Just add dates to where condition.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni not worked, same exception

Comment: @user12158375 what is `activedate`? Is it a column in one of your tables?

Comment: Yes it is a column of table1 i.e subquery table

Comment: I don't think that you should call to list on table2: `from o in db.table2
Select new {
o.ID,
COMPANYNAME=(db.table1.firstordefault())
}.ToList();`

Comment: @Vladimirs if yes then linq failed,

Comment: Can you provide full error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = db.table2
              .Select(s => new
              {
                s.ID,
                db.table1.Select(n => n.COMPANYNAME).FirstOrDefault()
              })
              .ToList()
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some text explaining how this post answers the question, so that other users can undertand and learn. Thank you.